# Jetpack Compose - Change startDestination of navigation dynamically in runtime

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Is there a way to dynamically change NavHost's `startDestination` parameter at runtime?

Problem:
I would like to show `on boarding` screen only the first time you start the app. Every next time it is started i want to show a login screen. Thats why i have to change `startDestination` dynamically in runtime.

However, every time i try to do this i'm getting an error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: List contains no element matching the predicate.
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:181)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:141)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$4$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:115)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$4$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:124)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:55)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:141)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2375)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2643)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3260)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3238)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3238)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3203)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:771)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1031)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:125)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:534)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:503)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:970)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:727)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@597e162, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@c2302f3, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@c07bb0, AndroidUiDispatcher@1c47a29]
```

My code:

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var splashViewModel: SplashViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            !splashViewModel.isLoading.value
        }

        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                val startDestination by splashViewModel.startNavigationDestination;
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

                Scaffold(
                    snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
                    content = { innerPadding ->
                        Surface(modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(innerPadding)) {
                            SetupNavGraph(
                                navController = navController,
                                startDestination = startDestination,
                                snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: String,
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState
) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
        onBoardingNavGraph(navController)
        authNavGraph(navController, snackbarHostState)
    }
}
```

```
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(private val getOnBoardingStateUseCase: GetOnBoardingStateUseCase) :
    ViewModel() {
    private val _isLoading = mutableStateOf(true)
    val isLoading: State<Boolean> = _isLoading;

    private val _startNavigationDestination = mutableStateOf(NavigationDestinations.OnBoarding.GRAPH)
    val startNavigationDestination: State<String> = _startNavigationDestination;

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getOnBoardingStateUseCase().collect { completed ->
                _startNavigationDestination.value =
                    if (completed == true) NavigationDestinations.Auth.GRAPH else NavigationDestinations.OnBoarding.GRAPH
            }

            _isLoading.value = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want seems to go against [the principles of navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles?hl=en#fixed_start_destination).

Comment: That link above (principles of navigation) is great! I think the onboarding screen could fall into the conditional navigation category though :thinking
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional